# Comments Layer not working in Parks Finder?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-local-government

I have installed and begun testing the [ParksFinder from ESRI](http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/park-and-recreation-finder/). I have managed to get it running, somewhat, but I keep hitting these weird walls.

My ArcGIS Server is a 10.1 Server.
My SDE DB is a 10.1 Geodatabase on SQL Server.
My WebAdapter is a 10.1 Adapter.
The Parks App I am using is 10.2.

in my config.js on line 132 [URL of CommentsLayer] I am pointing to:
http://maps.cityoftulsa.org/gis/rest/services/LGDM/Parks/MapServer/1

If I change this to a FeatureServer/1 (like the documentation says to) I get an error message whenever I click on a Park:

"**Required configuration key values are either null or not exactly matching with layer attributes, This message may appear multiple times.**"

After this message I get a spinner of doom... the page locks up.

But, if I keep that url pointing to:
http://maps.cityoftulsa.org/gis/rest/services/LGDM/Parks/MapServer/1

Then I can click on a park and in the popup window I can click on the Comments icon, type in a comment, give it a Rating, and click Submit whereupon I get the following error:
"**Unable to add comments. Comments table is either absent or does not have write access.**"

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you figure out a solution?

Comment: We actually turned off the comments for our map. But I did get them working. If I remember correctly it had to do with how it was published. You have to make sure it can be edited. If you still have problems let me know... I will try to help if I can.